# Issues setting up a router in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have setup multiple routers in typescript, but now in a new project i cant do it for some reason

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from './Components/Containers/Meplex';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router';

const App: React.FC = function () {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Container} exact />
      <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I have always used it like this, with  being in a

But now im getting

> Module '"react-router"' has no exported member 'Redirect'. Module
> '"react-router"' has no exported member 'Switch'.ts
>
> Type '{ path: string; component: FC; exact: true; }' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps |
> LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'.   Property 'component' does not
> exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps |
> LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'.ts(2322)

Im not having those issues in other typescript projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Switch` and `Redirect` are modules from [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)

So, install `react-router-dom` and then,

```js
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
```